# test ended after receiving only one remote engine's result, causing other engines connection refused

Tags: jmeter, distributed

When I run burden test on JMeter in CLI mode, using 4 remote servers, setting number of thread with 60. It ends before receiving all the result from the remote servers but only one. However if i use GUI mode to run this test, it works well. So I'm really confused.

I have tried to run the test on the remote servers separately, and it worked fine. So I think maybe there is something wrong in my settings or command..

here is my running command:

```
jmeter -n -t UserCheck.jmx -r -l result.txt -e -o webreport
```

where UserCheck.jmx is my test file, and the output in the terminal as follow:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using UserCheck.jmx
Configuring remote engine: 10.127.48.15:1111
Configuring remote engine: 10.127.48.27:1111
Configuring remote engine: 10.127.48.31:1111
Configuring remote engine: 10.127.48.32:1111
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Wed Apr 24 16:15:30 CST 2019 (1556093730629)
Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary +      1 in 00:00:01 =    0.8/s Avg:   297 Min:   297 Max:   297 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 145 Started: 194 Finished: 49
Tidying up remote @ Wed Apr 24 16:15:33 CST 2019 (1556093733529)
... end of run
```

part of the content of result.txt:

```
1556093732962,297,HTTP请求,200,OK,10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-34,text,true,,1273,275,51,51,https://starlight-18.nscc-gz.cn:9909/api/auth/login,297,0,271
1556093733063,196,HTTP请求,200,OK,10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-40,text,true,,1273,275,51,51,https://starlight-18.nscc-gz.cn:9909/api/auth/login,196,0,170
1556093733202,57,HTTP请求,200,OK,10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-48,text,true,,1273,275,51,51,https://starlight-18.nscc-gz.cn:9909/api/auth/login,57,0,32
1556093732593,667,HTTP请求,200,OK,10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-2,text,true,,1273,275,51,51,https://starlight-18.nscc-gz.cn:9909/api/auth/login,667,0,642
1556093733118,141,HTTP请求,200,OK,10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-43,text,true,,1273,275,51,51,https://starlight-18.nscc-gz.cn:9909/api/auth/login,141,0,116
```

the result is all from 10.127.48.15, nothing else generated...

and I login the servers separately to check the "jmeter-server.log", the content in the file on 10.127.48.15 is normal as(part of it):

```
2019-04-24 16:15:32,906 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-31
2019-04-24 16:15:32,923 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-32
2019-04-24 16:15:32,940 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-33
2019-04-24 16:15:32,957 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-34
2019-04-24 16:15:32,974 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-35
2019-04-24 16:15:32,991 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-36
2019-04-24 16:15:33,008 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-37
2019-04-24 16:15:33,025 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-38
2019-04-24 16:15:33,044 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-39
2019-04-24 16:15:33,059 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-40
2019-04-24 16:15:33,077 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-41
2019-04-24 16:15:33,095 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-42
2019-04-24 16:15:33,110 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-43
2019-04-24 16:15:33,127 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-44
2019-04-24 16:15:33,144 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-45
2019-04-24 16:15:33,160 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-46
2019-04-24 16:15:33,179 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-47
2019-04-24 16:15:33,195 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-48
2019-04-24 16:15:33,213 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-49
2019-04-24 16:15:33,229 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-50
2019-04-24 16:15:33,246 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-51
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-40
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-6
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-2
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-28
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-43
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-48
2019-04-24 16:15:33,262 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-52
2019-04-24 16:15:33,263 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-6
2019-04-24 16:15:33,263 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-2
2019-04-24 16:15:33,263 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-48
2019-04-24 16:15:33,263 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-40
2019-04-24 16:15:33,263 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-43
2019-04-24 16:15:33,263 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-28
2019-04-24 16:15:33,264 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-47
2019-04-24 16:15:33,264 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-47
2019-04-24 16:15:33,265 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-18
2019-04-24 16:15:33,265 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-18
2019-04-24 16:15:33,268 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-21
2019-04-24 16:15:33,268 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-21
2019-04-24 16:15:33,270 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-29
2019-04-24 16:15:33,270 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-29
2019-04-24 16:15:33,270 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-9
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-9
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-1
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-1
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-32
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-26
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-32
2019-04-24 16:15:33,271 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-26
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-13
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-13
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-31
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-31
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-44
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-3
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-24
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-39
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-44
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-24
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-3
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-42
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-20
2019-04-24 16:15:33,272 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-39
2019-04-24 16:15:33,273 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-42
2019-04-24 16:15:33,273 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-20
2019-04-24 16:15:33,276 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-27
2019-04-24 16:15:33,276 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-27
2019-04-24 16:15:33,276 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-45
2019-04-24 16:15:33,279 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-25
2019-04-24 16:15:33,279 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-45
2019-04-24 16:15:33,279 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-25
2019-04-24 16:15:33,279 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-7
2019-04-24 16:15:33,279 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-7
2019-04-24 16:15:33,279 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-49
2019-04-24 16:15:33,280 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-49
2019-04-24 16:15:33,280 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-53
2019-04-24 16:15:33,280 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-50
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-50
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-22
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-11
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-46
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-10
2019-04-24 16:15:33,282 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-4
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-46
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-30
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-11
2019-04-24 16:15:33,282 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-10
2019-04-24 16:15:33,281 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-22
2019-04-24 16:15:33,282 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-4
2019-04-24 16:15:33,282 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-30
2019-04-24 16:15:33,283 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-23
2019-04-24 16:15:33,284 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-23
2019-04-24 16:15:33,284 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-12
2019-04-24 16:15:33,284 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-41
2019-04-24 16:15:33,286 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-12
2019-04-24 16:15:33,286 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-41
2019-04-24 16:15:33,286 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-8
2019-04-24 16:15:33,285 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-16
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-33
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-8
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-16
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-33
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-14
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-5
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-38
2019-04-24 16:15:33,287 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-19
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-14
2019-04-24 16:15:33,289 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-36
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-37
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-19
2019-04-24 16:15:33,289 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-36
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-15
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-38
2019-04-24 16:15:33,291 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-37
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-5
2019-04-24 16:15:33,291 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-15
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-17
2019-04-24 16:15:33,288 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-51
2019-04-24 16:15:33,291 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-17
2019-04-24 16:15:33,291 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-51
2019-04-24 16:15:33,297 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-54
2019-04-24 16:15:33,306 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-35
2019-04-24 16:15:33,306 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-35
2019-04-24 16:15:33,309 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-34
2019-04-24 16:15:33,309 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-34
2019-04-24 16:15:33,314 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-55
2019-04-24 16:15:33,315 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-52
2019-04-24 16:15:33,315 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-52
2019-04-24 16:15:33,324 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-54
2019-04-24 16:15:33,325 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-54
2019-04-24 16:15:33,326 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-53
2019-04-24 16:15:33,326 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-53
2019-04-24 16:15:33,331 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-56
2019-04-24 16:15:33,338 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-55
2019-04-24 16:15:33,339 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-55
2019-04-24 16:15:33,348 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-57
2019-04-24 16:15:33,354 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-56
2019-04-24 16:15:33,354 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-56
2019-04-24 16:15:33,365 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-58
2019-04-24 16:15:33,376 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-57
2019-04-24 16:15:33,376 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-57
2019-04-24 16:15:33,382 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-59
2019-04-24 16:15:33,390 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-58
2019-04-24 16:15:33,391 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-58
2019-04-24 16:15:33,399 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-60
2019-04-24 16:15:33,406 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-59
2019-04-24 16:15:33,406 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-59
2019-04-24 16:15:33,427 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-60
2019-04-24 16:15:33,427 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.127.48.15:1111-UserCheck 1-60
2019-04-24 16:15:33,432 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-04-24 16:15:33,432 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Test Ended on 10.127.48.15:1111
2019-04-24 16:15:33,432 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Test Ended on 10.127.48.15:1111
2019-04-24 16:15:33,472 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Test Ended on 10.127.48.15:1111
2019-04-24 16:15:33,472 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Test Ended on 10.127.48.15:1111
2019-04-24 16:15:33,498 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Test has ended on host 10.127.48.15:1111
```

but in other servers' jmeter-server.log, the threads finished successfully but got error in the back, as follows:

```
2019-04-24 16:16:36,468 ERROR o.a.j.t.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper: Exception invoking listener on threadFinished.
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.16.172.200; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.threadFinished(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper.threadFinished(RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper.java:61) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:768) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:735) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:325) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    ... 13 more
2019-04-24 16:16:36,465 ERROR o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: sampleOccurred
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.16.172.200; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.processBatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender.sampleOccurred(BatchSampleSender.java:183) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender.sampleOccurred(DataStrippingSampleSender.java:112) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.sampleOccurred(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:95) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:70) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:980) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:569) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    ... 15 more
```

I guess the connection refused error is caused by that the connection is closed after the client running the command and receiving the result from the first server, because I found that after the process ended on the client, the server was still running some test threads. But I don't know how to solve it. Anybody met this problem before?

I expect an output of all results from all remote servers, and a webreport should be generated. But actually there is only one file generated, the result.txt, and only contains result from one server.

Comment: my Apache JMeter version is 5.1.1, java version is 1.8.0_221-b12

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue some time before with the same configuration. After some research found out that [related bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62795) was reopened, so probably there is some issue on jmeter side and hope they'll fix it soon.

But for now all what I can suggest is to downgrade jmeter version from 5.1.1 to 5.0.0. You can find it [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/). At least it helped us, so maybe it'll work in your case as well.